# 1.8.1 Error when trying to edit products

Tags: error, products

I am getting the horrible

> There has been an error processing your request

when I go to `Catalog\Manage` Products in the backend.

I'm using Magento ver 1.8.1.0.

This is what I get in the Error Log:

```
    **a:5:{i:0;s:88:"Source model "s2a/entity_attribute_source_measure" not found for attribute "s2a_measure"";i:1;s:3422:"#0 /home2/nimbusxv/public_html/cdpupstienda.com.mx/includes/src/__default.php(43353): Mage::exception('Mage_Eav', 'Source model "s...')
#1 /home2/nimbusxv/public_html/cdpupstienda.com.mx/includes/src/Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form.php(201): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Abstract->getSource()
#2 /home2/nimbusxv/public_html/cdpupstienda.com.mx/includes/src/Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Attributes.php(70): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form->_setFieldset(Array, Object(Varien_Data_Form_Element_Fieldset), Array)
#3 /home2/nimbusxv/public_html/cdpupstienda.com.mx/includes/src/Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form.php(144): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Attributes->_prepareForm()
#4 /home2/nimbusxv/public_html/cdpupstienda.com.mx/includes/src/__default.php(2591): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form->_beforeToHtml()
#5 /home2/nimbusxv/public_html/cdpupstienda.com.mx/includes/src/Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tabs.php(79): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#6 /home2/nimbusxv/public_html/cdpupstienda.com.mx/includes/src/__default.php(1966): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tabs->_prepareLayout()
#7 /home2/nimbusxv/public_html/cdpupstienda.com.mx/includes/src/__default.php(27705): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->setLayout(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout))
#8 /home2/nimbusxv/public_html/cdpupstienda.com.mx/includes/src/__default.php(27721): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('adminhtml/catal...', 'product_tabs')
#9 /home2/nimbusxv/public_html/cdpupstienda.com.mx/includes/src/__default.php(27488): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('adminhtml/catal...', 'product_tabs')
#10 /home2/nimbusxv/public_html/cdpupstienda.com.mx/includes/src/__default.php(27454): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#11 /home2/nimbusxv/public_html/cdpupstienda.com.mx/includes/src/__default.php(27459): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#12 /home2/nimbusxv/public_html/cdpupstienda.com.mx/includes/src/__default.php(13895): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
#13 /home2/nimbusxv/public_html/cdpupstienda.com.mx/includes/src/__default.php(13820): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
#14 /home2/nimbusxv/public_html/cdpupstienda.com.mx/includes/src/Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action.php(275): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->loadLayout(Array, true, true)
#15 /home2/nimbusxv/public_html/cdpupstienda.com.mx/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/ProductController.php(250): Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action->loadLayout(Array)
#16 /home2/nimbusxv/public_html/cdpupstienda.com.mx/includes/src/__default.php(13969): Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_ProductController->editAction()
#17 /home2/nimbusxv/public_html/cdpupstienda.com.mx/includes/src/__default.php(18331): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('edit')
#18 /home2/nimbusxv/public_html/cdpupstienda.com.mx/includes/src/__default.php(17865): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#19 /home2/nimbusxv/public_html/cdpupstienda.com.mx/includes/src/__default.php(20465): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#20 /home2/nimbusxv/public_html/cdpupstienda.com.mx/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#21 /home2/nimbusxv/public_html/cdpupstienda.com.mx/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#22 {main}";s:3:"url";s:81:"/index.php/admin/catalog_product/edit/id/26/key/2519e6f549ccb50fe82ead35ec124a56/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:5:"admin";}**
```

Any help Would be appreciated.

Everything seems to be in order, /TMP route, cache, don't know what it could be.

Answer (score 0):

There may be two reason for the issue:

### Source model not available:

As per error, you have using any `third party extension` and have provide  `dropdown/multi select attribute` source model .

On it confix.xml, source model  **s2a/entity_attribute_source_measure** has been declared but it class is not define. It class may be:

```
YourCustomModuleNamespace_YourCustomModulename_Model_Entity_Attribute_Source_Measure.
```

A sourcemodel provide all dropdown options of a attribute.

So **you need to find check the class is exits or not.need exit.then rerun compiler**.

Click [here](http://www.atwix.com/magento/frontend-backend-source/) what is source model

### [Compiler](https://kb.magenting.com/content/24/81/en/disable-magento-compiler.html) issue:

May the this `class is exits on Local/community codePool` but the `compiler did not copy to`  compiler location `/home2/nimbusxv/public_html/cdpupstienda.com.mx/includes/src/`

In that case, you need  **disable the  compiler rerun the compiler**
[See about compiler](http://alanstorm.com/magento_compiler_path)